# Finding duplicates based on multiple fields

Tags: database, ms-access

I've done a fair bit of researching, but haven't really found an answer that explains how to do this.

I've a table which records information about databases. This information has come from a range of sources and some of it is duplicated.

I've run a query to group all the tuples by System ID, the id of their host and their database name. This gives me about 1203 results. So my logic says that when all duplicates are removed, I should be able to do a group by query on *everything* and still get that number.

My next step was to run a group by query on the system id, host id, database name and the database version. This produces around 1300 results. In other words, I've created some 97 extra results that will contain duplication in them.

How can I find *which* 97 systems I've added?

My first thought was to do a simple join, including all the results in the second query and only those in the first query that matched - then return results from the first query that were null. But of course I haven't used the database version in the second table, so that doesn't work.

I've also tried using the MS Access Query Wizard and creating two queries which found all the duplicates in the data, one including database version and one not - then trying to get the difference. But again, I don't know what to link the results on.

**Edit**

In case my question wasn't clear enough, here is some sample data:

Original Table:

```
ID          Hostname          Database Name        Version
12          abc               abc                  10
12          abc               abc                  11
12          def               def                  11
12          def               ghi                  11
13          ghi               jkl                  10
```

So when I run my first query, grouping by ID, Hostname and Database, I get this:

```
ID          Hostname          Database Name      
12          abc               abc                                 
12          def               def                  
12          def               ghi                  
13          ghi               jkl
```

When I run my second query, grouping by ID, Hostname, Database AND Version, I get this:

```
ID          Hostname          Database Name        Version
12          abc               abc                  10
12          abc               abc                  11
12          def               def                  11
12          def               ghi                  11
13          ghi               jkl                  10
```

I know how to get rid of the duplicates when the fields are all common. What I want to do first though, is identify any systems that have duplicated IDs, Hostnames and Database Names but NOT identical Versions. Notice the one extra row in Query 2 compared to Query 1 - I want to perform a query to get JUST that row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you select those two result sets into two different temp tables and then

```
SELECT 
  someCommongField 
FROM 
  biggerTempTable  
 WHERE NOT IN 
    (SELECT someCommonField FROM smallerTempTable)
```

Comment: I don't know what to link on though. The first table produces 1300 results, hundreds of which are duplicated across three fields. But the second table produces 97 more results, which are duplicated across FOUR fields. I need to find which 97 results these are.

Comment: and the GROUP BY with a HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 doesn't help narrow it down?

Comment: I've added more detail to my question to help

Comment: In both of those queries add a field that shows count(*) and add a HAVING count(*) > 1, this will only return the rows that have more than one occurrence. I see where you are trying to go with it, and if that doesn't help create an sqlfiddle and post the link in here and we'll see if we can you straitened out

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access 2010 you can find duplicates using query wizard in the following way:

- launch query wizard
- select "Find Duplicates Query Wizard"
- select the table
- select all the fields (except ID - if you have it)
- select ID as the additional field (optional)

In the end, you'll see in the query the rows which contain duplicate values and you'll be able to delete the rows that you do not need.
You can find [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/find-and-remove-duplicate-data-HA010341696.aspx) an article about finding and removing duplicate data.

Comment: I've already said I tried this with no success. The first table produces 1300 results, hundreds of which are duplicated across three fields. But the second table produces 97 more results, which are duplicated across FOUR fields. I need to find which 97 results these are.